# OSX: Is there a log of connections?

Tags: networking, macos, logging

I am the original owner of this question [OSX log of connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/1171057/osx-log-of-connections)
but unfortunately something went wrong and i had to create a new account, so here i am. The question is: I was wondering if Mac OS X is having some sort of a log storing the connections that have interacted with the given computer? I cannot really seem to find it, therefore I am asking ;-) Thanks! 
To avoid further confusing, I am talking about info like ip addresses and not just connection has been established etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html). You can use it to log the complete traffic that runs over a given network interface. And then use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to investigate it further. You can also use Wireshark for both, logging and investigation in one step.

1. Open the  › System Information and identify the BSD device name of the network interface (AirPort, Ethernet etc.) you want to monitor
2. Open the Terminal.app
3. Run `sudo tcpdump -i en1 -s 0 -B 524288 -w ~/Desktop/DumpFile01.pcap` replace en1 with the name of step 1 and DumpFile01.pcap with the desired file name and path.
4. Press return and enter your password
5. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> if you've captured what you need

To view the file you can either print it by using `tcpdump -s 0 -n -e -x -vvv -r ~/Desktop/DumpFile01.pcap` or investigate it further using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

The dump contains everything that happened while the command was running. Including IPs, each package sent/received and so on.

More information on running tcpdump on macOS can be [found here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202013).

If you don't actually need logging you can also use [nettop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nettop.1.html) to view just the currently active connections.

**Ongoing logs**

There is no "access.log" that only contains network requests that I am aware of, but some network events may be found in `cat /var/log/system.log | grep en0` (replace en0 with your interface name) and WiFi related events in `/var/log/wifi.log`.

If you want a simple solution with UI that tracks your traffic on macOS the firewall [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) is a good companion. I use it myself.

Comment: Thanks! But what about for ip addresses that has interacted with the pc before starting to capture using that method

Comment: @step I've updated my answer regarding ongoing logging.