# MacOS log each connection with related process

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, logging, macos-bigsur

My new IDS is telling me that my host is behaving badly.
As I'm not sure of it, I'd need to investigate it further.
I'm working on a macOS Big Sur (11.2.1) host and, as soon as I receive a new suspicious event, I'd need to associate the process running on my Mac to such event.

The event (generated around once a day) includes information like `destination_ip:destination_port`.
Starting from such information, I'd need to map such connection to the corresponding process that generated it.
I know it is possible to retrieve the list of current network connections through `netstat`.
Nevertheless, as I receive the alert, the connection is already closed.
Hence, I'd need to "go back in time" on some kind of log, to retrieve the list of connections and related processes, and filter them on `destination_ip:destination_port`.

I've tried to run:

```
lsof -i -n -a -r5 > /tmp/connections.log
```

but it didn't work, I think, because from one log and the next one, the suspicious connection is closed.

Hence, another solution may involve a SIEM installation, but I prefer using something easier and quicker to manage, as my aim is just to identify if the event is a false positive or not.

Hence, how can I get the full log of network connections and related process?
I know that a traffic dump would collect all traffic information, but not information on the generating process.

Comment: You can try `tcpdump` or `ngrep` - will be much easier If the IP is a fixed one (or from a small pool of IPs). This is a related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1171113/osx-is-there-a-log-of-connections/1171122

Comment: Thank you. However, in this case, I would not be able to retrieve information on the process related to the connection, that is my primary goal.

Comment: It's possible with `tcpdump -k` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MacOS you should be able to get the process information easily with `tcpdump -k` - here's an example

```
sudo tcpdump -vvv -k NP
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
15:03:55.445666 (proc Google Chrome He:66290) ...
```

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/206822/log-network-traffic-with-process-id-on-mac-os-x